How do I switch my workspace from Team to Personal?
In the Notion onboarding, I mistakenly marked that my space would be used for team work, but I want to convert it back to a personal space. How do I do that?

By team, I mean that there are one or more "teamspaces" under that heading in the left sidebar. By personal, I mean mean having one Workspace heading on the left.

I read that I need to delete the teamspaces (and move any subpages I want out of that directory) but that just creates a list under the Private heading and I'd like to have one common Workspace heading.

It's tricky because you used to be able to downgrade from the Plans page in Settings but no longer. You don't have to delete your account to start over but it's true that you need to archive/delete the old teamspaces:
            
You'll be prompted if you want to move the subpages to your sidebar:
            
Now those pages will show under the Private heading, so to move them under a common Workspace heading, you'll need to "share" each page individually with the whole team (even if it's just you on your personal account):
            
Then those will show in the Workspace heading because they belong to your Notion instance's full team (even if, again, it's just you):
            
